# error en el filtrado de informacion

Tags: laravel-5

tengo un metodo al cual ago un filtrado,el problema es que cuando lo hace el filtrado me devuelve estos datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y como se puede ver no es un array el metodo es el siguiente:

```
$requisitos = $listaRequisitosPorListaServicios->filter(function ($requisito) {
            return $requisito->tipos->contains(function ($tipo) {
                return $tipo->nombre == "ANTIGUO" && $tipo->pivot->actualizacion;
            });
        });
```

la variable "$listaRequisitosPorListaServicios" esta llenada de la siguiente manera:
[image: datos]

no logro ver cual es mi error.

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el resultado esperado?

Comment: un array, me devuele un objeto como se puede observar en la primera imagen

Comment: Si estás filtrando una colección, te va a dar otra colección ...

Comment: si eso es lo que me deveria de dar pero no es mi caso ,ya probé muchas maneras y nada.

Comment: ¿Eh? ¿no dices que quieres un array? Definitivamente no entiendo nada.

Comment: si te fijs bien en la primera imagen es un objeto no es un array, mi objetivo es que sea un array

Comment: Si no explicas bien, no entendemos nada, no conocemos tu proyecto. Lo de la primera imagen parece la representación en json de un objeto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu variable `$requisito` tienes un array como lo esperas, el problema que tienes es que  tu función de filtro esta eliminando algunos posiciones del array y esta dejando solo la posición 1 según la imagen, al no estar ordenado tu array es decir posición 0, posición 1, posición 2, ocurre que al parsearlo a json pasa eso que presenta tu respuesta, lo que debes hacer es aplicarle un array_merge() a tu variable `$requisitos` para que lo ordene correctamente luego del filtrado y antes de parsearlo a json de la siguiente manera:

```
$requisitos  = array_merge($requisitos);
```

Comment: gracias ese era el error.